# How to adjust parent container size by the child container?

Tags: java, swing

More specifically, how to adjust JFrame size by its contentPane.

Here is the case, I am doing a 400*400 JPanel and I need it to fit in the JFrame. However if I set JFrame setSize(400, 400), some part of the JPanel would be hid due to the space occupied by the upper windows title bar.

I know I can just measure the border and the size of the title bar. I just want to know if there is better way to do.

---

Here is the solution that takes both `Hovercraft Full Of Eels` and `MadProgrammer` answer.

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    private Window() {  
        createUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Window();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createUI() {
        setContentPane(buildMainPanel());
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);   
    }

    private JPanel buildMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 640));
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);
        mainPanel.add(new Canvas(0, 0));
        return mainPanel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the panel's `getPreferredSize` method and return `new Dimension(400, 400)`.

On the frame call `pack`.  When called, `pack` will ask the content pane for it's preferred size, which is normally calculated by the layout manager (recursively ask each container for it's preferred size).

This will size the window so that's viewable area meets (as much as its possible to do so) the preferred size of it's content.

Answer (score 4):

> However if I set JFrame setSize(400, 400), some part of the JPanel would be hid due to the space occupied by the upper windows title bar.

You're making things too hard for yourself since the easiest solution is to simply not set the JFrame size. Instead call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding all components and before calling `setVisible(true)` and let it size itself to the optimum size for its components and layout managers.

Comment: @bijiDango: follow MadProgrammer's suggestion.